# Display a view in an overlay?

Tags: views, 6, modal-dialogs

I want to create a view of display type page with a path of '/%/bookmarks'. Whenever this view is linked on a page clicking on the link will open the view in an overlay instead of a new page. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you really asking for Drupal 6? I don't think Drupal 6 has overlays.

Comment: do you mean like a modal window?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I can think of for Drupal 6, would be to add some custom JavaScript to that page that scans all the links and attach a click handler on the links that matches the desired URL. Something like this:

```
$("a").each(function(){
  if (this.match('/bookmarks$/')) {
    $(this).click(function(){
      $.get(this.href, function(result) {
        $(result).find('#some .element').dialog();
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

The above code is written from memory, so is untested and probably flawed, but is can give you an idea of how to do it. The code requires jQuery UI dialog plugin to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think I can build on this to do what I want